# Is it possible to access the parent class (instead of the subclasses) when using single table inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sti

I have a Post class, with TextPost, ImagePost, and LinkPost subclasses (using STI).  These Post types are specified as strings in `Post.type` (as per STI convention).

I can call `TextPost.all`, `ImagePost.all`, and `LinkPost.all` just fine.

I thought I'd still be able to call `Post.all`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'text'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Post.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

For reference, here is the relevant part of my schema.rb:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "type"
  t.integer  "author_id"
  t.datetime "publish_datetime"
  ...
end
```

And my subclasses (each in their own appropriately-named .rb file):

```
class TextPost < Post
  ...
end

class ImagePost < Post
  ...
end

class LinkPost < Post
  ...
end
```

**Am I doing something wrong?  Or is it just not possible to (simply & succinctly) call the parent class when using STI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a row in your database with the type column equal to "text". Rails is trying to STI that to a `text` class. Looks like what you want is `TextPost` in the type column, not `text`.

Comment: Good call!  Had a record left over from my first attempt at STI (mis-labeled the class in Post.type as 'text', not 'TextPost').

Thanks for the help.